# How to handle UTF-8 using jackcon objectmapper with java

Tags: java, utf-8, jackson

How to handle UTF-8 using jackcon objectmapper using java pojo

the requirement is to handle other languages like Japanese,Chinese characters in Json payload as input to API for ex for creating customer as below

```
{
  "firstname" : "checkqa5",
  "lastname" : "テスト",
  "address1" : "498レッドアップルコート",
  "address2" : "道路番号567",
  "address3" : "test3",
  "city" : "Central Valley",
  "state" : "New York",
  "country" : "US",
  "email" : "qatest15112017212309@csp.com",
  "zipcode" : "10917",
  "workphone" : "76543211",
  "password" : "test123",
}
```

using Jackson library with java pojo to create json and using unirest for posting the payload. how to handle these special characters.

i have created a  java class holding the objects of payload using pojo format and passing data through constructor as below

```
CreateCustomerRequest user = new CreateCustomerRequest(testData);
```

"testdata" is data from excel sheet .  now i am using this request object to post using unirest as  below

```
rspString = Unirest.post(Endpoint)
                           .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                           .body(createjson(user))
                           .asString().getBody();

public String createjson(user)
{
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);

        return json;
}
```

when i print the returned string from above one it is printing "??????" in place of special characters

can any one help me .thanks in advance

Comment: Provide your code please. Jackson library support UTF8 by default.

Comment: Java handles the whole Unicode character space cleanly, with little intervention required.  You do need to ensure that the correct encoding is used, which might not be automatic, but specifics depend on the details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You're probably printing the string to a terminal which doesn't support such characters. Use your debugger, or write them to a file and open the file with a good text editor.